# Basic Javascript 2d Array issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find the intercept between two arrays. Sometime one of them is empty. For this I use underscore.

```
var fromDB = [[123],[]];
var result = _.intersection(fromDB[0]);
```

This does not work because `fromDB[0]` is `[123]` and not `[123],[]`. Do you know any way of getting `[123],[]`?

Comment: How can an empty array intersect with other arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify both of the indexes or use the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var fromDB = [
  [123],
  []
];

console.log(_.intersection(...fromDB));
console.log(_.intersection(fromDB[0], fromDB[1]));

fromDB = [
  [123],
  [123]
]

console.log(_.intersection(...fromDB));
console.log(_.intersection(fromDB[0], fromDB[1]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cool I didn't know about this operator!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the empty array that you created in fromDB , you need fromDB[1] , that is in this code snippet

```
_.intersection(fromDB[0],fromDB[1]);
```

I guess this is what you wanted .

Comment: no because fromDB could have more than two elements

Comment: If that is the case , I think spread operator is your best bet.